# Gulp running on OSX & Windows

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gulp

I'm new with Gulp, I have created my project in windows and installed/configured everything in my gulpfile, everything works fine.

My project is synchronized with Google Drive between my Windows 8 PC and macbook.
But when I run `"gulp"` command in osx this isn't working

> "Error: Cannot find module 'loadash.basevalues'

Node is installed in OSX and on a different project that I created in OSX it is working fine. Am I missing something? Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I can't find anything about this in Google

Comment: Did you try running `npm install` from your project dir? If not, try that.

Comment: Consider using git instead of Drive.

Comment: Not all node modules are platform-independent when installed. If you are syncing the `node_modules` folder, you may run into trouble.

Comment: @SLaks good idea, I'll try that, thanks. Should I run `npm i`?
@Trott yep but no changes, i still get an error
@AlexanderO'Mara Thanks for the info, I'll try to do this with Git like Trott said

Answer (score 0):

You should not move node_modules folder between your environments. Package.json file should contain all data and package names for you dependencies.

You can set up free remote git repository on services like github or gitlab, add .gitignore file inside root of your project, specify inside folders to exclude (node_modules obviously) and send it on remote git repository with "git push" command, to "git pull" any updates from your second location.

Remove entire node_modules folder on your OSX and run "npm install" or shorted "npm i". You might want to check if your node and npm versions are matching with "node -v" or "nodejs -v" and "npm -v" commands - if these versions are much different, consider to update your environment.